# How to MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a 16k rows table with columns like

`ID, author_name, letter;` (where letter is the first letter from the First Name)

I want to make a sql query that will list authors in groups of 3 for each letter from a-z

like:

### A

Albert,
Ana,
Antony,

### B

Ben,
Boston,
Bell,


How can I write this query ?
Thank you.

Comment: You can do this in your application. This is not a database problem. Sort and render. What front-end application language are you using?

Comment: can you show how your rows look like. Put up sqlfiddle

Comment: show us the table `structure` and a simple `select` to give you a good answer

Comment: I'm with @tadman on this one.  Grab the data ordered by letter and let the application sort out the fish from the fries.

Comment: I want to avoid the application to do the sorting and to get it from mysql. i think is more fast, less connections to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, :

```
set @counter =0, @letter:=''; 

select * from 
(select @counter:=if(letter=@letter, @counter+1,1) as counter, @letter = letter,  author
from table
order by letter, author) as t 
where counter<=3
order by letter, name
```

It works on comparing with previous value and restarting the numbering when letter changes else by incrementing.

Comment: This does not work, I get NULL data inside the letter column, and the counter does not increment because @letter does not get the letter column value?!.

Comment: Thank you @cjg ! Some tweaks and the query is complete. <code> select * from (select @counter:=if(letter=@letter, @counter+1,1) as counter, `@letter`:=letter as l,  author from abc_authors order by l) as t where counter<=3 order by l  limit 10;</code><br>Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

i have created the query for you

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM TABLE NAME ORDER BY id 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(author_name) FROM TABLE NAME ORDER BY id 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(letter) FROM TABLE NAME ORDER BY id
```

**now you will get result like this:**

```
A

Albert, Ana, Antony,

B

Ben, Boston, Bell,
```

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: i dont think group concat solves the problem as long as group_concat doesnot support limit.

Comment: i like your answer cjg nice solution